# EXCEL VBA - Error when copying from another instance of Excel to active workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

## What I would like:

I need to be able to copy only certain columns from another instance (Application) of excel that will be open, depending on the header.

## What I have so far:

```
Sub Import_Data()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim c As Range
Dim headrng As Range
Dim lasthead As Range
Dim headrng1 As Range
Dim lasthead1 As Range
Dim LogDate As Range
Dim LastRow As Range
Dim BottomCell As Range
Dim MONTHrng As Range
Dim Lastrng As Range
Dim PRIhead As Range
Dim LOGhead As Range
Dim TYPEhead As Range
Dim CALLhead As Range
Dim DEShead As Range
Dim IPKhead As Range
Dim COPYrng As Range
Dim MONTHhead As Range
Dim YEARhead As Range

With ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
Set wb = GetObject("Book1")

'If Book1 is found
If Not wb Is Nothing Then
    'Copy all Cells

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set lasthead1 = .Range("1:1").Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        Set headrng1 = .Range("A1", lasthead1)
        For Each c In headrng1
            If Left(c, 1) = "-" Then c = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 1)
            If Left(c, 1) = "+" Then c = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 1)
        Next c

        'Insert new column and format it to the month value of log date
        Set LastRow = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        Set LogDate = headrng1.Find(What:="Log Date", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set BottomCell = .Cells(LastRow.Row, LogDate.Offset(0, 1).Column)
        LogDate.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
        LogDate.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
        Set MONTHrng = .Range(LogDate.Offset(0, 1), BottomCell.Offset(0, -2))
        MONTHrng = "=Month(RC[-1])"
        MONTHrng.Offset(0, 1) = "=Year(RC[-2])"
        LogDate.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Month Number"
        LogDate.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Year Number"
        MONTHrng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "General"
        MONTHrng.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "General"


        Set PRIhead = headrng1.Find(What:="Priority", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set LOGhead = headrng1.Find(What:="Log Date", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set TYPEhead = headrng1.Find(What:="Type", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set CALLhead = headrng1.Find(What:="Call Status", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set DEShead = headrng1.Find(What:="Description", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set IPKhead = headrng1.Find(What:="IPK Status", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set MONTHhead = headrng1.Find(What:="Month Number", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set YEARhead = headrng1.Find(What:="Year Number", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        PRIhead.EntireColumn.Copy
    End With

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data").Cells.Clear
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data")
        'Paste Values
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        LOGhead.EntireColumn.Copy
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data")
        'Paste Values
        .Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        MONTHhead.EntireColumn.Copy
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data")
        'Paste Values
        .Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        YEARhead.EntireColumn.Copy
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data")
        'Paste Values
        .Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        TYPEhead.EntireColumn.Copy
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data")
        'Paste Values
        .Range("E1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        CALLhead.EntireColumn.Copy
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data")
        'Paste Values
        .Range("F1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        DEShead.EntireColumn.Copy
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data")
        'Paste Values
        .Range("G1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        IPKhead.EntireColumn.Copy
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data")
        'Paste Values
        .Range("H1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'Set Cells height to 15
        .Cells.RowHeight = 15
        'Set all Columsn to Autofit
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    'Clear the clipboard
    wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Close the Book1
    wb.Close False

Else
    'If no Book1 found display output
    MsgBox "Please ensure that you have opened the data from infra"
End If

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data")
    'Set all Headers as Range
    Set lasthead = .Range("1:1").Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    Set headrng = .Range("A1", lasthead)

    'Remove - or + from headers
    For Each c In headrng
        If Left(c, 1) = "-" Then c = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 1)
        If Left(c, 1) = "+" Then c = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 1)
    Next c




End With
ErrorHandle:

With ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

MsgBox "New Data has been Imported"

End Sub
```

## What doesn't work:

The issue appears to be with the past function.

## The error code:

> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

when debugging it highlights any of the following example of code:

> .Range("F1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

## My Findings:

At the moment I am having issues pinning this down to an exact point of failure. It seems to be random as to which paste fails. Sometimes the function completes without issue at all. The only thing that I can think off that appears to get it to work each time is to have the worksheet I am pasting on to active BEFORE I run the macro. The reason for thinking this is because when I select to debug it, the worksheet makes the "RAW Data" sheet active and then when I press either F8 or F5 to debug or run the code. It works without making any other changes.

## Other Notes:

- The workbook I am copying from is data exported from another application and I am wanting to fully automate a process. Therefore, this workbook has not been selected before the macro run. I am not sure if that would have any bearing on this issue?

Comment: Try to move this line `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data").Cells.Clear` before you copy data here `PRIhead.EntireColumn.Copy`. Say, first clear contents and then copy data.

Comment: Just before you posted that comment, I added `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data").Select` directly after `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data").Cells.Clear` and so far it isn't failing any more.

Comment: `Select` is not very good. Just for curious, put `PRIhead.EntireColumn.Copy` just after `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data").Cells.Clear`. Is it fix an issue?

Comment: No, that didn't work. It got all the way down to paste to "E1" this time and then the same issue occurred.

Comment: the main idea was that clipboard is very sensible to UI operations and when you clear cells in line `.Cells.Clear` - clipboard is clearing as well and that's why `PasteSpecial` fails - nothing to paste

Comment: But then why would it work all the way down to the 5th paste operation?

Comment: I've no idea. I don't see something wrong with your code. Maybe you have merged cells or something else?

Comment: I can confirm that there are no merged cells. However, I find it very odd that I just had it working completely fine 5 times in a row. I came back to this browser and back again to try once more and now it is failing. I suspect it is something to do with the copy source being in another instance of excel.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Can you share your workbook `Book1` e.g. using https://www.dropbox.com?

Comment: I'm afraid not as it contains some sensitive data for internal use only. I have managed to use a workaround for now: I have copied the entire worksheet to my active workbook and then completed the data sorting internal. So far this seems to work.

Comment: ok, last single test. Try to change all patterns `LOGhead.EntireColumn.Copy` and `.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` to `.Range("B1").EntireColumn.Value = LOGhead.EntireColumn.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like,

```
.Range("G1").PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: Add some explanation of what this does and how this will solve the problem

Comment: Just try it out.If you Google the PasteSpecial function, you can understand. And also it worked for me. :)